# Automatically change Sound Input Output device

Tags: sound

I have to plugin my USB Audio adapter ( 4300054 Gigawire USB Audio Adapter) for audio input because has a combo-input-output port for voice.  After I do this, I have go open Sound Settings and manually select the USB Audio adapter for Input and Output, if I do not, the system default remains selected.

Is there anyway, I can make Ubuntu to automatically select the USB Audio Adapter as the default as soon as I plug-in?

Answer (score 63):

There is [pulseaudio module-switch-on-connect](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-switch-on-connect) and [module-switch-on-port-available](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-switch-on-port-available) that enable automatic switching of an audio device on connection. See with the following command if any of these modules is already loaded:

```
pactl list short modules
```

If not, then test if you can make automatic switching work by issuing one or both of the following commmands in a terminal:

```
pactl load-module module-switch-on-connect
pactl load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

On success add one or both of the following lines to your `/etc/pulse/default.pa`

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect
load-module module-switch-on-port-available
```

This will then always load these modules on every login, resp. restart of the pulseaudio daemon.

Please note that local user settings in `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` will override the system-wide setting. If you have such a local file you will enter the above commands there.

If it still doesn't work, you may have conflicting settings in such a local `default.pa`. It then may worth to (temporarily) rename this file, followed by a restart of the Pulseaudio server before trying above again:

```
mv ~/.config/pulse/default.pa ~/.config/pulse/default.pa.old
pulseaudio -k
```

Comment: I just re-found this answer and wish I could upvote it again. This solves the issue on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: such a long time it is out there, and still not set to be loaded automatically in 16.04 :|

Comment: just applied this to 17.04 - perfect solution and really should be default

Comment: Tested and working on Mint 18 (Sarah)

Comment: What if `Module load failed` ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting `Module load failed` too - Mint 19.3. I'll have a dig around.

Comment: @Scaine: hi there :) good to see you again.  The module may have already been loaded (see `pactl list short modules`). PA spits out an error if we try to load a module twice.

Comment: Yep, pretty sure that's what's happening here, @Takkat. However, SteamVR isn't triggering the module when it starts up and creates the new input/output devices for some reason. But that's another issue!

Comment: @Scaine; did you try with the module `switch-on-port-available` - this one comes into action after the audio output port was changed. No idea which is involved in your case.

Comment: No joy, I'm afraid. I had `load-module module-switch-on-port-available` already specified in my /etc/pulse/default.pa. I also tried loading your version (which doesn't have the first use of "module" in its name), but SteamVR still creates the new output and I don't see any switching to it. This might be a SteamVR bug however, and I understand that this *does* work for some. Not to worry, it's not a big deal.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still need to switch devices.

Comment: @Heisenberg: you may try with edits I just made to this answer. If that still does not help your audio device may not allow switching.

Comment: @Takkat This and the last answer you wrote works only works for wired connections. When I connect my bluetooth device or through HDMI, it doesn't switch. Also, the audio switches automatically in windows so I think my audio device allows switching

Comment: @Heisenberg: I am really sorry to hear that - for me it works as expected with switching both, Bluetooth, and HDMI connections.

Comment: This worked on popos! (ubuntu 22.04)

Answer (score 27):

create `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` if it doesn't exist and append

```
.include /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

This is better than editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

Afterwards you should run `pulseaudio -k && pulseaudio --start` to have the changes take effect.  Thanks for pointing that out lreeder

Comment: Works for me on 16.04 LTS. You also need to restart pulseaudio after creating this config.  'pulseaudio -k' from the command line will do it.

Comment: Why is it "better than editing /etc/pulse/default.pa"?

Comment: I used this to get my connected headphones set as default after a restart, just editing /etc/pulse/default.pa did not work.

Comment: @Rodrigo because it is usually not a good idea to edit system-wide configuration files, which may be overwritten by an update and/or affect other users. See here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Configuration_files

Comment: @han-tyumi Of course! Thank you!

Comment: This works for me! But for some reason @Takkat 's solution didn't.

Comment: Seems to work on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 1):

I tested solutions for a long time that I could find in the documentation or on forums and this was the only one that worked.

So here is a script that I created that you can add when starting a session (unfortunately not for the entire computer because PulseAudio is a service that runs independently for each user).

```
#!/bin/bash
index=$(pacmd list-sources | egrep 'index|ports|analog-input-headset-mic' | egrep '\*\sindex:\s+[0-9]'  | cut -d':' -f2);

acpi_listen | while IFS= read -r line;
do
    if [ "$line" = "jack/headphone HEADPHONE plug" ]
    then
       pacmd set-source-port $index analog-input-headset-mic;
    elif [ "$line" = "jack/headphone HEADPHONE unplug" ]
    then
       pacmd set-source-port $index analog-input-internal-mic;
    fi
done
```

There is a solution which can be found on the first link of my sources, but it does not work for all PCs unfortunately.
Here are the links that allowed me to create this script

- [How do I automatically switch PulseAudio input to headset upon connection?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1267949/how-do-i-automatically-switch-pulseaudio-input-to-headset-upon-connection)
- [What code is executed when headphones are disconnected?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640741/what-code-is-executed-when-headphones-are-disconnected/642404)