# 18.10: how to set system default webcam?

Tags: lenovo, webcam, 18.10

My Lenovo X1 Carbon contains an IR camera as well as a standard camera, and it wants to default to the IR device, which produces garbled-looking video. It also seems to exacerbate a related issue in Chrome where selecting an alternate camera device doesn't work properly.

I haven't been able to find any good info on this. I can confirm my visible-light camera works properly by selecting it in Cheese preferences, but there seems to be no OS-level interface for setting the camera device in use (as there is for a sound device).

I'm comfortable in the terminal environment as well, but so far have not been able to find information on how to do this in the terminal either. Any advice or (up-to-date) references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI I fixed this by doing the following:

```
sudo mv /dev/video0 /dev/video0.original
sudo ln -s /dev/video2 /dev/video0
```

In my case, `/dev/video2` was the "standard" webcam. YMMV and some trial and error may be required.

Comment: N.B. that this fix continued to work when I upgraded to 19.04 Disco Dingo.

Comment: Great solution, quick and easy!! worx great on ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and ended up disabling the usb device for the IR camera, since I don't actually need it.
My solution is here: [How do I change the default webcam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119743/how-do-i-change-the-default-webcam/1119832#1119832)