# Lubuntu pulse audio volume control for short time applications

Tags: sound, lubuntu, pulseaudio, volume-control

I have an usb headset and I want to use it for Telegram voice messages. I tried to set the input device for Telegram in [pulse audio volume control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBIlj.png). The problem is, that I only can see applications in volume control as long as the application is recording. But I have to click on the recording button to record and I can't change the configuration in volume control at this time. How can I change the default input device or an input device for a specific application for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. It's not the best solution because I have to change the default source in command line instead of change the source for Telegram only with GUI. Therefor I hope that someone has better information but for now I can use Telegram with my usb headset.

I started Pulse Audio command line:

```
> pacmd
```

Then I searched for the index of my audio source

```
>>> list-sources
```

1 is the index of my headset, so I set the default device with

```
>>> set-default-source 1
```

Last, I had to restart Telegram messenger.

Comment: Did you try with [module-switch-on-connect](http://askubuntu.com/questions/158241/automatically-change-sound-input-output-device)? This should switch to your headset on plugging it in.