# How can I make indicator-sound showing controls for output that is actually playing?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

How can I make indicator-sound showing controls for output that is actually playing?

Whenever I connect my bluetooth headset, I get sound to my headphones as desired, but the Unity indicator control indicator-sound and all my sound control from keyboards are focused on default speaker sounds, not the one currently playing.

This results that when I plug in bluetooth device, it plays but volume control and mute is focused on other output device and to mute or turn down volume, I have to go to sound settings and change Output > Play sound trough.

This is how my settings look like even if sound plays trough bluetooth headset, I have to click Headset to make indicator work with Headset HT1+, but headset is playing sound.

Ubuntu version on this notebook is 15.10.

[image]

Comment: Try with [pulseaudio module-switch-on-connect](http://askubuntu.com/questions/158241/automatically-change-sound-input-output-device)

Comment: @Takkat Thank you, load-module module-switch-on-connect works as desired, it does switch sound and controls too, but only on connect, when I disconnect bluetooth, it does not switch output back to default audio, but thank you for pointing me in this direction, I am going to explore `/etc/pulse/default.pa` little bit more.

Comment: You can mark your default audio as "fallback" with the help of `pavucontrol`. It should then work as expected, provided you have the necessary default modules loaded (IIRC `module-default-device-restore` shoudl do that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Takkat's comment and question [pulseaudio module-switch-on-connect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158241/automatically-change-sound-input-output-device) it finally works and when Bluetooth headset is connected, volume controls and sound switches to newly connected device, when disconnected it falls back to default device.

Done by editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and adding these lines:

```
load-module module-switch-on-connect
set-default-sink "output name"
```

To get "output name", use `pacmd list-sinks | grep name:` and copy your desired output name wihtout the `<` `>`.

In my case for example it was `set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo`
would set `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo` as default device so when I disconnect headset, it would fallback to it.

Line `load-module module-default-device-restore` should be present and uncommented in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` by default, so no need to add it, but if it has to be added, it should be early in the config, there is a notice in the default.pa:

> This (module-default-device-restore) should be loaded as early as possible so that subsequent modules
>   that look up the default sink/source get the right value.

Pulseaudio must be restarted to make the changes in config effective. To just test it out effective until next restart, settings are possible with command`pacmd`:

```
$ pacmd set-default-sink "output"
$ pacmd load-module module-switch-on-connect
```