# Switch sound input when microphone is connected

Tags: 16.04, sound, microphone

I have a microphone that I sometimes connect to my computer for online meetings. When I connect it, I need to go into the sound settings and change input device.

Is it possible (in ubuntu 16.04) to have the input source automatically change when I connect the mic?

Comment: Did you try with [module switch-on-connect](https://askubuntu.com/a/158250/3940)?

Comment: The linked question only works for output not input.

Answer (score 0):

Could this indicator help out a little bit?

https://launchpad.net/~yktooo/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Max.