# Default Bluetooth audio mode set to HSP/HFP instead of A2DP 17.04

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 17.04, a2dp

I've successfully paired my BT Stereo headset that presents both A2DP and HSP/HFP profiles. However, by default, it starts with HSP/HFP profile active (I do can change it in Sound Settings manually).
The questions are about introducing some automated behavior:
- is there any method to force A2DP as default profile instead of HSP/HSF ?
- is there any method to set this BT device as default audio sink once it is connected? Now I need manually select the BT device every time I connect it, to let Ubuntu apps use it, the default is laptop speakers (Built-in Audio).

I wish it could work as in case of Windows/MacOS where whenever you connect the BT headset, it becomes default device and default profile for audio playback is A2DP rather than HSP/HFP.

Thanks in advance,

P.

P.S. The headset is DENON AH-GC20, Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Please try with modules: `module-card-restore` for restoring the port of your device. For auto-connecting see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/158241/automatically-change-sound-input-output-device

Comment: Thanks. Does not solve the problem unfortunately :(. BT Headphones still start as HSP/HFP device, moreover it is sometime impossible to switch it to A2DP through the GUI at all. I have to repeat it 2-3 times before it "catches" the idea to switch to A2DP or unpair/pair once more.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Debian, but the results are about the same from my experience. The only sure fire way I've found to ensure that Linux defaults to A2DP instead of HFP is to connect to a A2DP-only device before connecting to the dual profile device. Connecting to the A2DP-only device sets the default for some reason and then the dual profile device works great in A2DP mode. This is a pretty horrible experience.

Comment: I just switched to 18.04. Does not help either...